# BackboneJS How to load spotify playlists on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, iframe, spotify

Is there a way to only load embedded Spotify Iframes when hovering?

I have this Backbone App where I have bunch of playlists embedded inside an iframe, but the page is pretty slow and heavy because it loads all playlists at once.

I tried to add the `lazysizes`-plugin, but it doesnt seem to work/help (speed remains the same)

So, my HTML looks pretty simple:

```
<iframe class="lazyload playList" data-src="" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**EDIT**

Here is my script

```
this.collection.each(function(spotify, index) {
    var service = spotify.get('services').spotify,
        s=service.match(/[^\/:]*$/);
        $('iframe.playList').eq(index+3).attr('data-src', 'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:digster.dk:playlist:'+s);    
});
```

I have up to 16 playlists at once on a page, so the `data-src` is different for each iframe of course

Anyone have an idea or suggestion?

Comment: Can you give me an example with your lazySizes attempt? (I'm the author of it). It's my duty to see what I can do! (Have you also tried to lower lazySizes expand option to something like 10?)

Comment: well, basically I just added the `lazysizes`-plugin to eh page (by using RequireJS) and then adding the class "lazyload" to my iframes... but I almost hink that i hasn't to do with it, its more the spotify API e.g. spotilocal which causes the issue of slowing down the page...

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would do:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjw7o9ha/

Basically, you create all the iframes without the `src`, and on hover, you use jquery to set the source.

This is just an example, you can create a much better code starting from this.

Answer (score 0):

Using mouseover directly on an iframe might be problematic, because an iframe is a different document.

In case you have used lazySizes (I hope you not hsut added the class, but also changend src to data-src) you can try to so something like this:

1. Add iframe with data-src, but without class="lazyload"
2. On domready or later on window.onload add the class lazyload

   <iframe data-src="spotify.html">/iframe>

   $(window).on('load', function(){
       $('iframe[data-src]').addClass('lazyload');
   });

Comment: Hmm interesting approach, but it didnt solve it... I'll blame the Spotify API :-)